# What is End-to-End Testing

Tags: e2e

We are debating in our team if we should call our test end-to-end testing or regression testing.

Can you explain in detail the difference between the two and what is the scope and coverage?

Answer (score 4):

A test can be both an end-to-end test and a regression test.

The term "end-to-end testing" describes the scope of the test. End-to-end testing simulates real-world user scenarios and workflows with all of the components, including dependencies to the extent possible, of the system under test in place.

The term "regression testing" describes the purpose of the test. Tests run as regression tests are designed to assert that an intended change to the system did not introduce any unintended side effects or defects.

If you are developing a new feature, you will likely develop various types of tests, including end-to-end tests, to verify that the feature works as intended and designed. Once these tests have been run and passed, they may be run to ensure that later changes did not introduce a regression.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas for your comments, appreciate it.

Comment: An important note: During test strategy and planning it is critical to define what are the "ends" for end to end testing. Generally the in scope and out of scope sections cover the ends/boundaries, what is regression vs new testing, etc. Then ends of e2e are particularly fuzzy when dealing with a suite of features across one or more products that could be combined to create a single workflow or customere experience.

Answer (score -2):

Certainly! Both End-to-End Testing and Regression Testing are important aspects of software testing, but they serve different purposes and focus on different aspects of the testing process.

**End-to-End Testing:**

**Purpose:** End-to-End Testing (E2E Testing) is designed to validate the entire software application workflow from start to finish. It aims to ensure that all components of the system work together as intended and that the application behaves as expected in a real-world scenario.

**Scope and Coverage:** E2E Testing covers the entire application, including all interconnected components, modules, and systems. It tests the flow of data and processes across the entire application to identify any issues that may arise when different parts of the system interact. This type of testing typically simulates real user scenarios.

**Regression Testing:**

**Purpose:** Regression Testing is performed to ensure that new code changes (additions, modifications, or bug fixes) do not negatively impact the existing functionality of the software. The primary goal is to detect and fix any unintended side effects that may occur due to code changes.

**Scope and Coverage:** Regression Testing focuses on specific areas of the application that are affected by recent code changes. It doesn't necessarily cover the entire application but rather the parts that could be impacted by the modifications. The scope is narrower compared to E2E Testing, and it is more concerned with maintaining the stability of existing features.

**In summary:**

When deciding whether to call your test "End-to-End Testing" or "Regression Testing," consider the nature of your tests. If you are testing the entire application workflow, it's more appropriate to label it as End-to-End Testing. If the focus is on ensuring that recent changes haven't introduced regressions, then Regression Testing is a more accurate term. Often, teams may perform both types of testing to ensure the overall health and quality of the software.

Comment: This answer has several characteristics associated with using Generative AI, but it is not attributed. It is a Network-wide policy that [the use of Generative AI is appropriately referenced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384648/572) to comply with the [policies on attribution and plagiarism](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it assumes end-to-end testing and regression testing are mutually exclusive. Can an end-to-end test be a regression test? Of course, it can. When constructing a suite of regression tests, I include both unit, integration, and end-to-end tests, with proper proportion and stability (see test pyramid).

Comment: @ThomasOwens, out of curiosity, how have you identified those characteristics?  What are those characteristics? Can you give examples of them in this particular answer?

Comment: @dzieciou As a moderator on other sites in the network, I have access to heuristics developed and approved to make such determinations. Unfortunately, I can't share the specifics. You can find [a few mentions of these heuristics on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=AI+heuristic).

Comment: @ThomasOwens... You are right I generated this answer using AI model which I am trying to train from last few month ... good to hear that we have review model in place in stack exchange to prevents AI generative answers, I will update it with my answer.  thanks for shearing ref links

Comment: I have one question these bot answer are trained over human answer data set so how will someone make deference if a human answer characteristic match with bot trained bot one ?  like its pretty much possible that  human being can answer in the same way like bot ...right ?